# jQuery: Change the border color of ONE table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple HTML table of options here:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>cream</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS with the relevant styles:

```
td { background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #3F3F3F; cursor: pointer; }
td.selected { color: #D93A2C; border: 1px solid #D93A2C; }
```

Looks like this:

[image: HTML Table]

When I click on one of the table cells, I want the border and text to be red. So I use jQuery to toggle the '.selected' class using the following code.

```
$('td').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

However the result is this:
[image: HTML Table Cells Selected]

The first table cell (blue) is the only one that looks as I want when selected. I need all the borders of the selected cell to be highlighted.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'm not opposed to ditching tables if someone can suggest a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works nicely for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table { border: 1px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse; }
    td { border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000; }
    td.selected { border: 1px solid #F00; }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>blue</td>
        <td>green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>red</td>
        <td class="selected">yellow</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks, I wasn't aware of the border-collapse property.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **very** hack'ish way of getting the job done, might spark an idea on your end to produce something better... I've not fully tested it across browsers but worked on IE8,chrome,FF. **[Live example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/GtAwW/)**

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>XYZ</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>2346</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XYZ</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>2346</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XYZ</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>2346</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('td').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).prev('td').css('border-right','#ff0000');
        $(this).parent().prev('tr').find('td:nth-child('+(this.cellIndex+1)+')').css('border-bottom','#ff0000')
    });
});
```

CSS

```
table{
      border-collapse: collapse;
}

td { border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:3px }

.selected{
    border-color:#ff0000;
    color:#ff0000;
}
.selected-bottom{
    border-bottom-color:#ff0000;
}
.selected-right{
    border-right-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, this does work but jnpcl's solution is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to put a DIV in each cell then add the treatment to the DIV.

Comment: The issue I had with using DIVs is that the borders double up. e.g, 2 DIVs next to each other with a 1px border would have a 2px border between them.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS [`outline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#dynamic-outlines) may be useful here, as it may be on top of other borders (which is the problem here).

Comment: I tried messing with this... CSS outlines seem to go outside the border, not on top -- even if I specify no border for 'td.selected' it still shows up 1px outside where the border would be.